# SPD2010 Hide Field if Name in Field != Current User

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to hide a field based on who the Current User is. 
I have multiple fields that have  names in them, ex: Approver 1, Approveer 2, etc...
I want only the Approver 1 to be able to edit the Approver 1 section. 
Can I hide fields if "Approver 1" does not equal [Current User]?

I've tried going into conditional Formatting and selecting "Hide" when "Approver 1" Not Equal "[Current User]" but when I go to my form, the field is hid even though I should be able to see it because Approver 1 IS the current user (me).